# System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection: What is the equivalent of RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing, owin

I'm trying to change a webapi project to use OWIN, based in part on this article:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

However this appears to involve changing my `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` method from using a  `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection` to a `System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection`.  How would I do the following with the `HttpRouteCollection`?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(HttpRouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");  // No IgnoreRoute extension for HttpRouteCollection?
```

Or am I approaching this all wrong?

The main driver for this is I am using signalR in the project, but because it seems to automatically use OWIN I've ended up with a mix of configuration in Global.asax (for webapi stuff) and OwinStartup class (for signalR) and I'm prefer to do it all in one place.

Comment: Web API currently does not have an extension like `IgnoreRoute`. Also, as far as I remember ELMAH doesn't have support for Selfhost yet, so you cannot use it there. I would not recommend shifting from WebHost to Selfhost scenario just for the sole reason of  configuration as the two hosts have some differences.

Comment: Ah I'm not actually going so far as to Self Host, just moving all my configuration into the Owin Startup class.